# Override a Dataview in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I would like to override the bql query which is present in the appaymentlist dataview. shown in the screen shot below.

[image]

when i try to override appaymentlist in graph extension, I am unable to implement if() statement because of private "Cleared" field defined in the base graph.

My question are

1. How do I implement if() condition statement in the PXOverride dataview.
2. If I omit if() condition in pxoverride , will the base appaymentlist() implement if() condition statements. I mean , will the override "appamentlist" merges with the base "appaymentlist()"
3. What is the best way to override to implement such scenario?

any suggestions would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: do not screenshot the code pls.

Comment: @saikiran The suggestion was that you **not** post screenshots.  Please paste your code here *as text*, not as images.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Screenshots of code are bad but the relevant content needed to provide an answer was all there so I upvoted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override a private field so what you need to do is:

1. Locate every location where the private field is used.
2. Copy paste/override all these location in your customization.

Sometimes these locations can be private too. In that case you need to find every location that calls into private elements and replace them.

Comment: Thank you very much Hugues Beause'jour. i have a small doubt. Creating a delegate for base dataview and passing it into the customized dataview in Ext Graph will that also work?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the exact question. If it's regarding overriding data view and data view delegate. Copy pasting from base graph to your extension like you did in your question should replace the base elements with yours.